# What's the advantage of using if(0 == foo()) rather than (foo() == 0)?

Tags: java, c++, coding-style

I found that some programmers would like to code like this in the comparator operator. I found it is more difficult to read...

```
if (0 == foo()){
    ....
}
```

Is there any different between `foo() == 0` in term of readability ? What's the advantage of using 0 ==foo()?

Comment: I am with you, I find this less readable (as it is not natural). But there was a push about a decade ago to put the 0 first as it prevents accidental assignment when you forget to use '==' and use '=' instead. Personally I find this argument very weak as the compiler actually warns you (and I compile with the flag that converts all warnings to errors so it would fail to compile for me so it is never a problem).

Comment: @Martin: If I'm not mistaken, that argument is more applicable for C, where you don't get a warning for that, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No I think the best reason to do it like this:

```
0 == foo
```

is to make sure you don't forget one `=` which would make it

```
if (0 = foo)
```

which will usually raise a compiler error rather than

```
if (foo = 0)
```

which creates a hard-to-find bug.

Comment: And just about every C++ compiler will warn about this. I get `warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression` in Visual C++ when I write something like `if(foo = 0)`. And I set my compiler to turn warnings into errors, so I actually haven't been bit by this.

Answer (score 6):

In that case there is no difference but when comparing strings it is a good idea to use the string constant first to avoid a null pointer exception.

i.e.

```
if ("somestring".equals(someVarString)) {
// doSomething
}
```

So someVarString can be null and the test is still valid.  Whereas if you flip the test to:

```
if (someVarString.equals("somestring")) {
// doSomething
}
```

it will cause an NPE if someVarString is null.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of this style is that in all cases the compiler is guarenteed to complain if you type `=` rather than `==` because you can't assign to a numeric.

For example

```
  bool a = 1;
  if (0 = a) 
  { }
  else if( 1 = a ) 
  { }
```

will not compile,
whereas

```
bool a = 1;
  if (a = 0 ) 
  { }
  else if( a = 1 ) 
  { }
```

is not illegal (it is likely to produce compiler warnings)

That said, I agree that is looks ugly, and usually do it the other way round.

Comment: The compiler will complain anyway, because `int` isn't a `boolean` expression as required by an `if` condition.

Comment: Its a weak argument for an advantage as the compiler will generate a warning anyway.

Comment: Completely agree, just giving a reason why its sometimes done

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance, no.

Readability is subjective; I personally find `0 == foo()` slightly more awkward to read than `foo() == 0`.

The only argument I've seen in favour of `if (0 == var)` is that if you accidentally mistype this as `if (0 = var)`, the compiler will complain. However, most modern compilers will issue a warning when they see `if (var = 0)`, rendering the argument moot. Besides, this line of thinking isn't even applicable to your case since `if (foo() = 0)` isn't valid code.

Comment: Yes i agree with you, that's why i curious why some ppl like to code in that way.

Answer (score 1):

there's no performance impact, the reason people do it is to ensure they cannot accidentally type the = operator instead of the == comparison operator (as the compiler would complain you cannot assign to a constant).

I find that the readability penalty is more than I like, so I don't do it. Others have obviously gotten used to it.